# Automatic table of figure credits

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, pdftex

In many of my projects I end up including a lot of external figures, like

```latex
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{something.png}
    \caption{An illustration of something.}
    \label{fig:foo}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

These figures are often taken from somewhere else and Creative Commons licensed, and some of them require attribution. Either way, I generally include a table of all figures at the end of the document, like

```latex
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline
 Figure & Author & License \\
 \hline
 1 & John Smith / Wikimedia Commons & CC-BY-SA 3.0 \\
 \hline
 2 & Jane Doe & CC-BY-NC 3.0 \\
 \hline
 3 & Own Work & Public Domain \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

The problems with this are:

- I have to do the table markup for every project I make;
- The attribution and license information is far from the figure it applies to in the source code, making it harder to maintain;
- If the figure numbers or relative ordering of the figures were to change, I would need to manually update the table.

I'm aware of the existence of `\listoffigures`, but it doesn't seem to have the kind of format I want; I don't need the page numbers nor the captions, and I would much rather have the figures listed in a table like the above.

In my ideal use case, I'd prefer to be able to include such information inline when creating the figure, like

```latex
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{something.png}
    \caption{An illustration of something.}
    \label{fig:foo}
    \author{Jane Doe}
    \license{CC-BY-NC 3.0}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

and then put something like `\tableoffigures` at the end of the project to make the table automatically. I'd also like to be able to put this in a separate package that I could just `\usepackage` in order to make the necessary changes (I know this is technically a different question, but I wouldn't know how to modify a solution to include this feature).

How could I do this? Other tips are welcome; I'm not too knowledgeable about LaTeX so if this would be easier to accomplish with a different environment than `\begin{figure}` or a separate package then that would be fine.

Comment: Stepwise refinement: Try defining and including a new environment, say {license}, within {figure}. Finally use package extract ( https://ctan.org/pkg/extract ) to pick out all those {license} environments. Refine from there.

Comment: An alternative to extract may be script mathgrep, seee https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605146/how-to-extract-equation-environments-or-other-blocks-inside-a-latex-document , when you have PERL installed.

Comment: I would define of list of attribution/credits with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61086/how-to-create-my-own-list-of-things

Answer (score 1):

See, if is sufficient to indicate source of image at figures, for example by use of the `copyright` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}%
                {Source: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}
\caption{Caption title}
\label{fig:right}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\copyrightbox[r]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck-portrait}}%
                {Source: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}
\caption{Caption title}
\label{fig:right}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `author` and `license` information to the `\listoffigures` (I don't see why you do not want a list of figure titles and the pages they are on). Here is a revision of your MWE

```
\begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{something.png}
    \caption{An illustration of something.} %% puts it in the LoF
    \label{fig:foo}
    \author{Jane Doe}
    \addtocontents{lof}{Author Jane Doe}
    \license{CC-BY-NC 3.0}
    \addtocontents{License CC-BY-NC 3.0}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

You can, of course, change your `\author` and `\license` macros to automatically add the arguments to the LoF.

In any case **do not use the `center` environment within floats** as it adds unwanted vertical spaces, just use `\centering`.

Comment: I appreciate the pointer towards `addtocontents`, but I'll wait to see if someone else can match the formatting a bit better. I would definitely prefer to have a proper table rather than a list. It seems like the `etoc` package can do almost exactly what I want, but only for the table of contents - it doesn't support the list of figures.