# How do I create a solution manual for a textbook which uses xsim (v0.20) for its exercises?

Tags: xsim

I am writing a textbook using LaTeX. Within the textbook I am using the xsim package to create the exercises and their solutions. I would like the printed textbook to contain the exercises only and I would like to be able to print a separate solution manual with just the solutions (and preserving cross references from the textbook). What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

**One approach**: If you embed ex&sol and other parts in dedicated environments (`\begin{tbd} .. \end{tbd}`), you can extract them; tbd stands for to-be-determined, i.e. you either use standards of define your own ones.

See here for some solutions: [How to extract equation-environments (or other blocks) inside a Latex document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605146/how-to-extract-equation-environments-or-other-blocks-inside-a-latex-document/605147#605147) .

**A second approach** is to put them into separate files, which you can include in as many documents as needed via `\input` (modularization).

As you can see, both approaches are the inverse of the other ;-) Perhaps the second one is more practical and easier to organize.

Yes, they both are unspecific to `xsim`, i.e. will work with almost anything.