# Binding texstudio indent section shortcut

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

I was wondering if there is any way to bind a keyboard shortcut to this exact button in the IDE.

I can't find it in: "options > configure TexStudio > shortcuts"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken the time to email Benito van der Zander, the maintainer of TexStudio: https://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Here is his answer:

> I do not think so.
> You have to right click on the section to choose the section. Even if there was a shortcut, it would not know which section to indent.
> The current selection can be indented with tab.

So it is impossible as of 2022 December.